# Composition of linear orders on the same set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I need to show an example of finite linear orders $K_1$ and $K_2$ are defined on the same set, such that their composition $K_1\circ K_2$ is not a transitive relation.

Whatever orders I choose, their composition is a transitive relation.

Any ideas?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general result: if $K$, $L$ are transitive relations and $KL=LK$ then  $KL$ is transitive.

Comment: @user14111: Certainly. But the condition $KL=LK$ looks more nicely :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the 5-element set consisting of the five elements a, b, c, d, e. Let $K_1$ order these elements in the order e, c, d, a, b. Let $K_2$ order them in the order d, e, b, c, a. Under the composite relation $K_1\circ K_2$, transitivity fails for the triple a, c, e.

Comment: "so that eK1cK1dK1aK1b and dK2eK2bK2cK2a." 
I do not understand this notation.
May you explain this?

Comment: I understood, thx :)